# Do I need a transit visa for Turkey if I have an onwards flight from IST

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, transit-visas, layovers, istanbul

I am an Indian citizen flying from Glasgow to New Delhi. I am changing planes in Istanbul Airport, with a layover of about 4 hours before going to New Delhi in India. My issue is that I am using 2 non aligned airlines, KLM from Glasgow to Istanbul and Indigo from Istanbul to Delhi, India. Do I need a transit visa, since I have to collect my bags and check in again for the other airline?

Comment: It doesn't matter if the airlines are "aligned". It does matter if you're traveling on a single ticket, or you have booked the two flights separately.

Comment: Booked the two flights separately. Hence this dilemma.